# self.children count doesn't give correct number

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have this method that is supposed to loop through my nodes and check how many tubes I have in my parent, and if it is less than 6, I should add more. The first 6 work, but after they are removed by the remove action [self.children count] still reports that they're are 6 tubes still there. It logs "Tube Amount: 6/6" even though on screen the node count is at 0. I need an accurate way to see how many nodes I have. here is my code:

```
-(void) checkTubes {
    int amt = 0;
    SKSpriteNode *last;
    for(SKSpriteNode *node in self.children)
        if(node.size.height > 100) {
            last = node;
            amt++;
        }
    NSLog(@"Tube Amount: %i/%i", amt, [self.children count]);
    if(amt < 6) {
        for(SKSpriteNode *node in self.children)
            if(node.size.height > 100)
                last = node;
        SKSpriteNode *tube1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"tube"];
        SKSpriteNode *tube2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"tube2"];
        int x1 = 155;
        int y1 = -100;
        int x2 = x1;
        int y2 = y1+tube1.size.height + 68;
        if(last != (id)[NSNull null]) {
            x1 = last.position.x + x1;
            x2 = x1;
        }
        tube1.position = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
        tube2.position = CGPointMake(x2, y2);
        [self addChild:tube1];
        [self addChild:tube2];

        SKAction *actionMove1 = [SKAction moveTo: CGPointMake(tube1.position.x - 1600, tube1.position.y) duration: 15.55f];
        SKAction *actionMove2 = [SKAction moveTo: CGPointMake(tube2.position.x - 1600, tube2.position.y) duration: 15.55f];
        SKAction *actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        [tube1 runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove1, actionMoveDone]]];
        [tube2 runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove2, actionMoveDone]]];

    }
}
```

Comment: `children` looks to be a collection, may be an array. And you are not removing anything from this `children` array. Hence you are getting count 6. You are only changing the `last` pointer here and there.

Comment: Perhaps an `SKAction` doesn't like being added to two nodes simultaneously.  Have you tried creating a separate `[SKAction removeFromParent]` for each tube?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya You may have overlooked the fact that he's adding an `[SKAction removeFromParent]` to each child, which should remove the children from the `self.children` array when it executes.

Comment: does [self addChild:] add to multiple places?

Comment: The on-screen count represents only the number of nodes in view. Also, the amt variable and the [self.children count] will return the same. How do you go about removing the nodes?

Comment: with the actionMoveDone action

Comment: you need to copy the remove action. Also (unrelated) you can simply test for last!=nil the use of NSNull is superfluous. Do use brackets around evere for/if/etc it'll save you many troubles down the road an makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same action for multiple nodes without copying the action. This might fix it:

```
    SKAction *actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [tube1 runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove1, actionMoveDone]]];

    // 2nd and any following use of the same action must be a 'copy'
    [tube2 runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove2, [actionMoveDone copy]]]];
```